# Maven Surefire: Error occured in starting fork

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

When I am trying to  run

> mvn test

I always get the Error Message that maven-surefire error ocurred in starring fork. It has something to do with my local settings, on my colleagues PC it's working fine. I hope that somebody has an idea what is wrong with my pc :)

A part of the Error Message:

1. > [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
   >       org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
   >       (default-test) on project exercise00-assignment01: Error occurred in
   >       starting fork, check output in log -> [Help 1]
   >           org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal
   >       org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
   >       (default-test) on project exercise00-assignment01: Error occurred in
   >       starting fork, check output in log
2. > ```
   > Caused by:
   >     org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: Error
   >     occurred in starting fork, check output in log
   >         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork
   >     (ForkStarter.java:284)
   > ```

I am using win10, jdk: 1.8.0_202, maven: 3.6.0

My **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>at.tuwien.swtesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>exercise00-assignment01</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging> 

    <name>01-RingBufferTest</name>
    <description>Entry exercise.</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>junit</groupId>  
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
            <version>4.12</version>  
            <scope>test</scope>  
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: First please upgrade to at least 2.22.1 of maven-surefire-plugin....

Comment: Where do I need to Update this Version? I can't modify the pom.xml

Comment: You can't modify the pom? does not make sense...

Comment: The pom.xml is from my course lecture, normally it should also work with this settings. On my colleagues PC it is working with this file.

Comment: Please show the full error output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added the following Code to my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

The Error Message changed:

> [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump,
>   [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream. [ERROR] Error occurred in
>   starting fork, check output in log [ERROR]
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: Error
>   occurred in starting fork, check output in log [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:623)
>   [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
>   [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)

Edit

I finally found my problem, in my path to the folder there was an '&' and windows couldn't handle it. This was the reason for the different Error Messages

Comment: Do you mean "&" is in the cmd.exe string? Mine is "cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Users\someone\tools\jdk-8u211\jre\bin\java -javaagent:C:\\Users\\someone\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.7.201606060606\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\someone\\abc_repo\\bbb_repo\\services-parent\\payment-services-settlement-impl\\..\\target\\jacoco.exec,append=true -noverify -Duser.timezone=US/Central
                                -Duser.language=en org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire5536645681570537156 ..."

Comment: It is very long. Don't know how to make it short.

Answer (score 10):

I recently stuck in the same issue. After a lot of research, I got below the resolution

ForkCount should be set as "0"

Update your pom file as:-

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <suiteXmlFiles>`enter code here`
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I tried on 3.0.0-M3 version too and build is created successfully

Comment: I think this appears to work because it is skipping tests. Be very careful about using it! Maven also warns about it now

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me after trying numerous other suggestions was having a fork for every test class. Setting fork to 0 worked intermittently which I expected to work as when run with debug=true, they passed each time (no fork in debug).
3.0.0-M4

[surefire forkcount documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount)

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <forkCount>number of test classes</forkCount>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this on my MacBook and it was fixed by restarting the computer. Not a very satisfying fix but it worked.